# Grouping array of objects (collection) by adjacent integer property

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, lodash

I am trying to group an array of object by a property `int` so that I get a nested array and have each item grouped where it's next value is `n + 1`. With the assumption that the starting array is in the correct order.

```
const value = [{int: 1}, {int: 2}, {int: 3}, {int: 15}, {int: 16}, {int: 21}]
const result = [
  [{int: 1}, {int: 2}, {int: 3}],
  [{int: 15}, {int: 16}],
  [{int: 21}],
]
```

Comment: please add your try.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate with [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for each `int` decide if to add to current sub array or add with a new sub array, according to the existence of last sub array, and the delta between current and last item:

```js
const value = [{int: 1}, {int: 2}, {int: 3}, {int: 15}, {int: 16}, {int: 21}]
const result = value.reduce((r, o) => {
  const last = r[r.length - 1];
  
  if(last && last[last.length - 1].int + 1 === o.int) last.push(o);
  else r.push([o]);
  
  return r;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const {each, last} = _

function groupByIncrementingProp (collection, prop = 'key') {
  const results = []
  var bundle = []
  each(collection, (obj, key) => {
    if (!bundle.length || (obj[prop] - 1) !== last(bundle)[prop]) {
      bundle = []
      bundle.push(obj)
    } else if (obj[prop] - 1 === last(bundle)[prop]) {
      bundle.push(obj)
    }
    if (!collection[key + 1] || obj[prop] + 1 !== collection[key + 1][prop]) {
      results.push(bundle)
    }
  })
  return results
}

const value = [{key: 1}, {key: 2}, {key: 3}, {key: 15}, {key: 16}, {key: 21}]

console.log(groupByIncrementingProp(value))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.core.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a simple for loop does it:

```
 const result = [];
 let previous = value[0], acc = [value[0]];

 for(const current of value.slice(1)) {
   if(current.int === previous.int + 1) {
     acc.push(current);
   } else {
     result.push(acc);
     acc = [current];
   }
   previous = current;
 }
 result.push(acc);
```